# Magento website broken, appearing to try to update

Tags: magento-1.7

So this is really puzzling me.

I've been asked to take a look at a Magento based website after it stopped working.

The error when accessing the website is here: http://pastebin.com/pKUm1Tby

All I know is that it is Magento version 1.7.0.2.

I'm struggling to get any sense out of the current hosts. They did not develop it and the original developers are no longer around.

Comment: I think this error occurred on changing the website from one host to another host..

Comment: Try by creating another sample database and check whether site gets connected to it or not?? If not then the problem is with the file as named there. You need to copy the same file from another magento software..(download a new one)...

Comment: Try this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/223447/...